# How to pass data-id value of anchor tag to Code-Igniter controller function and show result in data-modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm working on Code-Igniter project and I'm trying to show data on click event of anchor tag. For that I'm passing `data-index` value using `AJAX` to `Controller` and to `Model`. After that I'm getting result, but the result is not shown in `modal-box`.

**Here is my Code:**

***View:***

```
<a id="propDetail" name="propDetail" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-index="<?= $property->property_id; ?>" 
    title="Details of <?= $property->property_code; ?>" 
    data-target="#myModal" class="open-Details">
    <?= $property->property_code; ?>
</a>
```

***AJAX Code:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.open-Details').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url : '<?= base_url(); ?>property',
      data: {
        propDetail: $(this).data("index")
      },
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm putting the value in variable in controller.

***Controller Code:***

```
public function index()
    {   

        $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        $data['username'] = $user->username;
        $data['user_id'] = $user->id;

        $id=$this->input->post('property_id');
        $area=$this->input->post('area_id');
        $cluster=$this->input->post('cluster_id');
        if( $area =='') {
            $area =0;
        }
        if($cluster == ''){
            $cluster=0;
        }

        $propDetail = $this->input->post('propDetail');

        $data['areas'] = $this->p->area();
        $data['clusters'] = $this->p->cluster();
        //$data['clusters'] = $this->p->clusterAll($area);
        $data['title'] = 'Property List';

        $data['properties'] = $this->p->getPropertyByAreaCluster($area, $cluster);
        $data['propDetails'] = $this->p->defectsView($propDetail);

        $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('Property/property_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

***Model Code:***

```
public function defectsView($propDetail)
   {
        $query = $this->db->query("call modalView(?)", $propDetail);
        if ($query) {
            $data = $query->result();
            $query->next_result(); 
            $query->free_result();
            return $data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
   }
```

I'm getting result if I'm passing hard coded value to the procedure (I'm using Stored Procedure).

***Here is my Modal view:***

```
<div class="modal fade displaycontent" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" id="propertyDetails" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content displaycontent">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Property Datails of</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-striped ">
          <tbody>
            <?php if($propDetails) { 
              foreach ($propDetails as $propDetail) { ?> 
              <tr>
                <td>Property Code:</td>
                <td><?= $propDetail->property_code; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Defect Added DAte :</td>
                <td><?= $propDetail->property_added_date; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Room ASYS No.:</td>
                <td><?= $propDetail->property_ASYS_no;?></td>
              </tr> 
              <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><?= $propDetail->property_address_1;?></td>
              </tr> 
              <tr>
                <td>Room Count:</td>
                <td><?= $propDetail->rooms;?></td>
              </tr> 
              <tr>
                <td>Defect Count:</td>
                <td><?= $propDetail->defects;?></td>
              </tr> 
            <?php } } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Edit:***
**here is my output:**

[image]
I'm not getting, where I'm made a mistake. Any kind of help is welcome, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending response via AJAX, you need to **echo** the output. Else ajax will get blank the response.

Also depending on how you send the response add dataType in ajax. 
Eg: is sending html response add **dataType:'html'**, if sending json response add **dataType : 'json'**

JS CODE :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.open-Details').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url : '<?= base_url(); ?>property',
      data: {
        propDetail: $(this).data("index")
      },
      dataType :"html"
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

PHP CODE :

```
echo $this->load->view('Property/property_view', $data,true);
```

Comment: I'm using a Code-Igniter framework, so its not possible to echo out, since it gives an error message: Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string.

Comment: I'm just put the modal code after my view code. And I'm calling that modal on click event of anchor tag.

Comment: When you load view. add "true" as a 3rd parameter.

Comment: Still it gives blank modal-box, please check updated question.

Comment: Just confirm, when the page loads, property list is shown using :  $this->load->view('Property/property_view', $data); ?

And on page load itself you have modal view created ? which is hidden at start before the ajax call ?